# Xaml UWP buttons hide/show not working using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

When i press the button the appbarbutton and slider doesnt hide. 
When i debug i can confirm the "Collapse or Visible" is been notified. 
Not sure what mistake i do. Please help to fix the issue.

I am building for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) for xbox one.

```
<Page
x:Class="AvProStreaming.MainPage"
IsTabStop="false"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AvProStreaming"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="RosyBrown">

<SwapChainPanel x:Name="DXSwapChainPanel">
    <Grid x:Name="ExtendedSplashGrid" Background="#FFFFFF">
        <Image x:Name="ExtendedSplashImage" Source="Assets/SplashScreen.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

    <Slider x:Name="slider" Background="Cyan" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,444,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="46"
          Visibility="{Binding IsHide}" />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="150" >

        <AppBarButton Foreground="Cyan" Icon="Back" Name="Backward" Label="Back" Click="MenuItem_Selected" 
                     Visibility="{Binding IsHide}" Margin="30"/>
        <AppBarButton Foreground="Cyan" Icon="Play" Name="Play" Label="Play" Click="MenuItem_Selected" 
                     Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="30"/>
        <AppBarButton Foreground="Cyan" Icon="Pause" Name="Pause" Label="Pause" Click="MenuItem_Selected" 
                     Visibility="{Binding IsHide}" Margin="30"/>
        <AppBarButton Foreground="Cyan" Icon="Forward" x:Name="Forward" Label="Forward" Click="MenuItem_Selected" 
                     Visibility="{Binding IsHide}" Margin="30"/>

    </StackPanel>

</SwapChainPanel>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge _bridge;

    private SplashScreen splash;
    private Rect splashImageRect;
    private WindowSizeChangedEventHandler onResizeHandler;

    private Visibility _IsHide;
    public Visibility IsHide
    {
        get { return _IsHide; }
        set
        {
            _IsHide = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsHide");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }......

private void MainPage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Keydown");

        if (!App.IsXbox())
            e.Handled = true;

       if (e.OriginalKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.GamepadMenu)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("GamepadView button clicked");
            IsHide = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting the binding mode explicitely: `{Binding IsHide, Mode=OneWay}`

Comment: I added mode but it didnt work plz

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint in the setter method and see if it is getting updated?

Comment: The _IsHide value is "Collapsed" when i set a breakpoint in the setter. But the xaml part is not getting upated. If i explicitly set visibility to collapse in xaml it works.

Comment: You need to debug and see if everything is called in the right order.
After the button click, the setter should be called. In the set the OnPropertyChanged(...) should be called. Is PropertyChanged != null and gets raised (for "IsHide")? After this the get for IsHide should be called, is this happening as well? What is the get for IsHide returning?

Comment: The _isHide is 'visible' and value is 'Collapsed'.
Next step _isHide is 'Collapsed' and value is 'Collapsed'
Next step The PropertyChanged is 'null' and this statement is skiped 'PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));'

Comment: So when PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); is skipped no one will ever know that "IsHide" has changed and the UI wont update...

Comment: Thanks for helping in debugging

Answer (score 0):

Bindings without explicitly specified source object require that the target element's `DataContext` (or that of one of its parent elements) is set to an instance of the class the owns the binding source property.

So adding `DataContext = this;` to the constructor fixed the issue.